# Add item to top of LinkedHashMap

Tags: java

I am using LinkedHashMap in my code.This is my map:

```
LinkedHashMap<String, Conversation> conversationsMap=new LinkedHashMap<String, Conversation>();
```

I am adding items to this map with following line:

```
conversationsMap.put("test",Conversation);
```

But this line adding item to last.I need to add this item to top of this map.How can I do this ?

Answer (score 5):

LinkedHashMap retains insertion order.To add it to first you need to iterate through older map and insert values in a new map.

Answer (score 4):

The purpose of a linked hash map is to preserve the order items were added in, that's why it goes at the end.

You could create a new linked hash map with the new item and add all the others at the end.

I can't see any methods in the API docs that would do it in any other way.

Comment: Thank you.I am using this map in a arraylist.Now I am reversing the list to achive that.Is this a good approach ?

Comment: Not sure how expensive it is to reverse a list. My solution is pretty clean though. Give it a go!

Comment: Can you give an example for this ?

Comment: Create a new linked hash map. Add new item. Add all items from old list.

Comment: How can I add all items from old list.I have to use loop ?

Answer (score 1):

There is a new method [putFirst()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html#putFirst(K,V)) in Java 21:

```
conversationsMap.putFirst("test", Conversation);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the standard JDK provides a way to do this. Basically the LinkedHashMap retains insertion order, adding the new entry in a new map and then the other entries from the old map would be inefficient, as you'll have to iterate through all the entries of the old map each time you want to add a new key-value pair.

One workaround would be to create your own pojo and use a `LinkedList<MyData>` with the `addFirst` method. If you need the uniquess of the keys, you could have in parallel a `Set<String>` to check this constraint.

```
class MyData {
     private final String key;
     private final Conversation value;
     //constructor, getter, hashcode, equals
}
```

Otherwise there is a [`ListOrderedMap`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/collections4/map/ListOrderedMap.html) in `Apache Commons Collections`, which provides `put(int index, K key, V value)` method (never tested) but it should do the trick.

Comment: @Okan I don't get it. _"I am using this map in a arraylist"_. It means you have a list of maps? If yes, then I don't get the purpose of your question, since you are speaking about the map itself.

Comment: No,you got it wrong.I am doing like this: http://prntscr.com/5ed4ds I am adding items to last of map then i am reversing the list and last item will be top of the list.Is this a good approach for performance or etc.

Comment: @Okan Well you have to copy the values in a new list and then reverse it. Basically a O(n) operation. This is not so bad but with my solution (Pojo + LinkedList + HashSet for key uniqueness), getting the conversation in the order you want wouldn't require to copy the values and reverse them, since you already got them in the right order (`LinkedList#addFirst` and `HashSet#contains` are constant time operation).

Comment: @Okan This is not the best but this is not worse, you are just doing unnecessary computations. With this you need to copy and reverse each time you want to get the conversation values in the order you want.